# XHR upload onprogress Event not Working on HTTPS Connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, https, xmlhttprequest

I have a setup for uploading files to AWS S3 via Angular 7 and Node.Js. The upload works fine. But there is an issue with the `xhr.upload.onprogress` event.

This event is only triggered when hosting the server via `http`. When using an `https` connection, the event isn't triggered once.

I tested it on heroku and my EC2 instance and came to the conclusion that only `http` works. Therefore, my production app hosted on AWS via `https`, doesn't work, either.

Here is the code (write a comment if more details are needed):

**Angular Service (Frontend)**

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let progress = 0;
xhr.upload.onprogress = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
    console.log('xhr on upload', event);
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        progress = 100 * (event.loaded / event.total);
        console.log('file upload progress', { progress, file });
    }
};
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('POST', `${API_URL}/${this.API_PATH}/upload`, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', this.authService.getAuthToken());
xhr.send(payload);
xhr.onload = () => {
    observer.next(xhr.response);
    observer.complete();
    alive = false;
};
```

**Node.Js**

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })
        busboy.on('finish', async () => {
            const fileData = req.files.file
            const fileId = req.body.fileId
            await uploadToAws(fileData)
            // ...
        })
        req.pipe(busboy)
    } catch (err) { /* ... */ }
}
const uploadToAws = async (fileData, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            Body: fileData.data,
            Bucket: awsConfig.buckets.drakery,
            ContentType: fileData.mimetype,
            Key: `mykey`,
            StorageClass: 'ONEZONE_IA',
        }
        awsConfig.s3
        .upload(params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data.Location))
        .on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
            console.log('httpUploadProgress', evt);
        })
})
```

I am really confused why this is happening. I couldn't find any resources online on this problem.

I am really thankful for every help!

Thanks

Comment: What does `xhr.onload` do? Try removing it, see if it works. You could also add a `content-type` header to the request.

Comment: `xhr.onload` is called when the request finished... I added a `content-type` and removed `xhr.onload` but it still doesn't work with a https connection

Comment: Does the file get to your Node.js server or does it not even get that far when served over HTTPs? Are you sure you aren't accidentally making a cross origin request by doing something like posting to HTTP:// instead of HTTPS:// when serving over HTTPS? What does the value for your host equal when it works and what does it equal when it does not?(I am talking about `${API_URL}/${this.API_PATH}/upload`)

Comment: The file reaches the server fine (also via https) --- I don't make a cross origin request ---- API_URL = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}:3000/api

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to use? Have you tried explicitly adding `https` as part of the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: When hosting the website on on `https` the url looks like `https://example.com/api/...` and on `http` it looks like `http://example.com/api/...` So that should be fine

Comment: I'm having the same issue - but I don't know if it's https related. I'm also trying to get it work on EC2 over AWS.

Comment: @friek108 Really strange. Maybe you can checkout this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782997

Answer (score 1):

this is my basic js code that I have used for a web project:

```
        ...
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);

        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

        xhr.open("POST", "/controller");
        // fd : formData
        xhr.send(fd);

    }

    function uploadProgress(evt) {

        if (evt.lengthComputable) {

            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            ...
        }

        else {

            ...
        }

    }
```

As you can see I'm adding an event listener on 'progress', I'm not overwriting the other callback function like you do with (=) ( maybe https uses another callback and by overwriting the onprogress like you do the callback does not work properly ):

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
    console.log('xhr on upload', event);
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        progress = 100 * (event.loaded / event.total);
        console.log('file upload progress', { progress, file });
    }
};
```

Try this out, hope it helps you, have a nice day

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, but unfortunately, the event isn't triggered, too :(